# Accessing internet inside container behind a corporate proxy

Tags: proxy, docker, docker-for-windows

I'm running docker daemon on windows and have configured my daemon to use proxy using my username and password. I successfully pulled a `ubuntu:latest` image from docker hub but as soon as SSHed the container and tried `apt update`, it didn't work. An interesting thing to notice was that it tried to connect to Ubuntu Repo server directly.

I then configured the `apt.conf` file and it started using the proxy but, for some reason, the authentication fails. I've checked and double checked that the syntax and my password are correct.

I removed the `apt.conf` file and configured the proxy in `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` environment variable but it's still the same. Authentication failure.

I tried using both, and again, the authentication failure. This is what I get:

```
root@24e4053eeaf4:/etc/apt# apt update
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  407  Proxy Authentication Required [IP: <IP> 8080]
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
  407  Proxy Authentication Required [IP: <IP> 8080]
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  407  Proxy Authentication Required [IP: <IP> 8080]
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
  407  Proxy Authentication Required [IP: <IP> 8080]
Reading package lists... Done
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is not signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  407  Proxy Authentication Required [IP: <IP> 8080]
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease' is not signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease  407  Proxy Authentication Required [IP: <IP> 8080]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  407  Proxy Authentication Required [IP: <IP> 8080]
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease  407  Proxy Authentication Required [IP: 10.137.20.70 8080]
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Any idea?